# How to display roundof time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

```
ID Intime Outtime

001 00.21.00 00.48.00
002 08.23.00 13.45.00
003 00.34.00 00.18.00
```

I need to display the time time like 30 minutes or 1 Hours, it should display a roundoff time

Expected Output

```
ID Intime Outtime

001 00.30.00 01.00.00
002 08.30.00 14.00.00
003 01.00.00 00.30.00
```

How to make a query for the roundoff time.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Are those the actual data (in varchar format)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round the current date to 30 minutes like:

```
select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi,0,getdate())/30*30, 0)
```

Explanation: this takes the number of minutes since the 0-date:

```
datediff(mi,0,getdate())
```

Then it rounds that to a multiple of 30 by dividing and multiplying by 30:

```
datediff(mi,0,getdate())/30*30
```

The result is added back to the 0-date to find the last 30 minute block

```
dateadd(mi, datediff(mi,0,getdate())/30*30, 0)
```

This can be adjusted easily for 60 minutes. :)

Comment: That is not rounding, that is merely truncating

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DATEDIFF, DATEADD and DATEPART. You should be able to do what you want with that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Here is kind of a step-by-step routine. I'm sure you can do something shorter and even more efficient. It would also simplify a lot if you used a `datetime` data type instead of a string.

```
declare @T table (id char(3), intime char(8), outtime char(8))

insert into @T values ('001', '00.21.00', '00.48.00')
insert into @T values ('002', '08.23.00', '13.45.00')
insert into @T values ('003', '00.34.00', '00.18.00')

;with
cteTime(id, intime, outtime)
as
( -- Convert to datetime
  select
    id,
    cast(replace(intime, '.', ':') as datetime),
    cast(replace(outtime, '.', ':') as datetime)
  from @T
),
cteMinute(id, intime, outtime)
as
( -- Get the minute part
   select 
     id,
     datepart(mi, intime),
     datepart(mi, outtime)
   from cteTime  
),
cteMinuteDiff(id, intime, outtime)
as
( -- Calcualte the desired diff
  select
    id,
    case when intime > 30 then (60 - intime) else (30 - intime) end, 
    case when outtime > 30 then (60 - outtime) else (30 - outtime) end 
  from cteMinute
),
cteRoundTime(id, intime, outtime)
as
( -- Get the rounded time
  select
    cteTime.id,
    dateadd(mi, cteMinuteDiff.intime, cteTime.intime),
    dateadd(mi, cteMinuteDiff.outtime, cteTime.outtime)
  from cteMinuteDiff
    inner join cteTime
      on cteMinuteDiff.id = cteTime.id
),
cteRoundedTimeParts(id, inHour, inMinute, outHour, outMinute)
as
( -- Split the time into parts
  select 
    id,
    cast(datepart(hh, intime) as varchar(2)) as inHour,
    cast(datepart(mi, intime) as varchar(2)) as inMinute,
    cast(datepart(hh, outtime) as varchar(2)) as outHour,
    cast(datepart(mi, outtime) as varchar(2)) as outMinute
  from cteRoundTime 
),
cteRoundedTime(id, intime, outtime)
as
( -- Build the time string representation
  select 
    id,
    right('00'+inHour, 2)+'.'+right('00'+inMinute, 2)+'.00',
    right('00'+outHour, 2)+'.'+right('00'+outMinute, 2)+'.00'
  from cteRoundedTimeParts
)
select *
from cteRoundedTime
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking the range

```
select ID,
   DateAdd(mi, DateDiff(mi, 0, Intime +
      case when InMi >= 15 then 30 - InMi else - InMi end), 0) as Intime,
   DateAdd(mi, DateDiff(mi, 0, Outtime +
      case when OutMi >= 15 then 30 - OutMi else - OutMi end), 0) as Outtime
FROM
(
select ID, Intime, Outtime,
datepart(mi, InTime) % 30 InMi,
datepart(mi, Outtime) % 30 OutMi
from tbl
) X
```

or by using the classical trick equivalent to Int(x+0.5)..

```
select ID,
    dateadd(mi, ((datediff(mi, 0, Intime)+15)/30)*30, 0) Intime,
    dateadd(mi, ((datediff(mi, 0, Outtime)+15)/30)*30, 0) Outtime
from tbl
```

#### IF you want to ROUNDUP instead

(you have a value going from 00.34.00 to 01.00.00) Then you need this

```
select ID,
    dateadd(mi, ((datediff(mi, 0, Intime)+29)/30)*30, 0) Intime,
    dateadd(mi, ((datediff(mi, 0, Outtime)+29)/30)*30, 0) Outtime
from tbl
```