# How to display the time with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server

Table1

```
ID  |  Intime  |   Outtime
--------------------------
001 | 00:21:00 |  00:48:00
002 | 08:14:00 |  13:45:00
003 | 00:34:00 |  00:18:00
```

Time format: HH:MM:SS

Tried Code.

```
SELECT dateadd(mi, datediff(mi,0, Intime)/30*30, 0) AS 'Intime'
  FROM Table1
```

Above Query giving the result for 30 minutes or 1 hours, which means minutes less than 30 then it is displaying 30 minutes, minutes greater than 30 then it is displaying 1 Hours

I need to display the time like 15 minutes, 30 minutes or 1 Hours, it should display a roundoff time with condition

Conditions are

```
If minutes is less than 15 minutes then it should display exactly 15 Minutes, for example 03:15:00
If minutes is greater than 15 minutes and less than 45 minutes then it should display exactly 30 Minutes, for example 03:30:00
If minutes is greater than 45 minutes then it should display exactly 1 hour, for example 04:00:00
```

Expected Output from the table1

### ID  |  Intime  |  Outtime

```
001 | 00:30:00 | 01:00:00
002 | 08:15:00 | 14:00:00
003 | 00:30:00 | 00:30:00
```

How to make a query for the roundoff time with condition.

Need Query Help

Comment: Very strange set of conditions, why skip :45 intentionally??

Comment: First of all, I see nothing wrong when people ask for a ready solution, like you do. It's fine by me, even if it is a trivial problem. Now, the plenty of your past similar questions aside, you have just recently asked a question about a problem that is virtually identical to this. Why don't you just modify the accepted answer to that question to meet your new requirement? I may be wrong, but from where I'm sitting it seems as if for some time the community has been writing every line of code for you. Now I'm curious, is it a big project? Is it going to be free/open-source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal interpretation of your question:

```
select id,
InTime = DateAdd(mi,
    case
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), intime) = '00:00:00' then 0
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), intime) <= '00:15:00' then 15
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), intime) <= '00:45:00' then 30
    else 60
    end, DateAdd(hh, DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), 0)),
OutTime = DateAdd(mi,
    case
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), OutTime) = '00:00:00' then 0
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), OutTime) <= '00:15:00' then 15
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), OutTime) <= '00:45:00' then 30
    else 60
    end, DateAdd(hh, DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), 0))
from tbl
```

But given your output, your third rule should have been

> If minutes is greater than [OR EQUAL TO] 45 minutes then it should display exactly 1 hour, for example 04:00:00

So the query becomes

```
select id,
InTime = DateAdd(mi,
    case
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), intime) = '00:00:00' then 0
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), intime) <= '00:15:00' then 15
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), intime) < '00:45:00' then 30
    else 60
    end, DateAdd(hh, DATEDIFF(HH, 0, intime), 0)),
OutTime = DateAdd(mi,
    case
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), OutTime) = '00:00:00' then 0
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), OutTime) <= '00:15:00' then 15
    when DateAdd(hh, -DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), OutTime) < '00:45:00' then 30
    else 60
    end, DateAdd(hh, DATEDIFF(HH, 0, OutTime), 0))
from tbl
```

---

#### RE your previous question

You accepted an answer [in your previous quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912584/how-to-display-roundof-time) that always **ROUNDED DOWN** when there was an answer there that rounded properly?  The description is not correct

> Above Query giving the result for 30 minutes or 1 hours, which means minutes less than 30 then it is displaying 30 minutes

It doesn't.  `select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi,0, '09:21')/30*30, 0)` returns `09:00` which rounds DOWN.